# Core data files exported with underscore

Tags: objective-c, core-data, mogenerator

When I go to Editor-->CreateNSManagedObjectSubclass, and export my entities, they show up as the entity names... but another person who was working on my project before seems to have exported as their name with an underscorebefore, and these files look totally different on the inside...So I'm confused as to what's going on. Here's a google doc that contains a few relevant screenshots... Check out the second page to the two sections of fields. I'm sort of confused by them:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BMBqJME91Njb69JS4x3bvH0-KSmC-KLBl6QglE22jmQ/edit?usp=sharing
Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on [MOGenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator), since that's apparently what your predecessor used to generate the managed object classes. By default MOGenerator generates base classes prefixed with an underscore and initially generates stub subclasses (the ones without the underscores).

You can then write any custom code in the subclasses. That way, whenever the model changes, you can regenerate the base classes without worrying about clobbering your custom code, since by default MOGenerator won't regenerate the subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! So if I want to add a attribute to a class, I can just add it in the model and the underscore classes will automatically update?? Or if not, how do I tell the underscore classes to update?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'add an attribute to a class.' Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: add a string atrribute to core data entity

Comment: Right. As I say, you'll need to do read up on MOGenerator and then take a look at how it's configured in your local environment. The first thing I'd check is whether your project already has a target set up to run the `mogenerator` command line tool. If so, just running the target should do the trick, though it's possible you may need to separately download and install the tool first.